# Twig include finding set when in a file.

Tags: include, set, twig

I am trying to use twig / include to pull content from two files where the second file passes as a variable the 'set' content from the first. The problem is that the 'set' content cannot be seen when it comes from a file. As an example, this works

```
{% set localContent %}
  <div> someContent </div>
{% endset %}

{% include 'MyBundle:Templates:some.html.twig' %}
{% include 'MyBundle:Templates:main.html.twig' with {
  'includedContent':     localContent,
} %}
```

where main.html.twig is simply:

```
{% block form_row %}
<div> mainContent </div>
{{includedContent}}

{% endblock form_row %}
```

and some.html.twig contains:

```
{% set fileContent %}
  <div> someContent </div>
{% endset %}
```

When I change the includedContent variable to fileContent which is defined in a file I get an exception that indicates fileContent cannot be located.

Is what I am trying to do possible ?

Can anyone help me, I would like to get this application finished before the world ends in a few days :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another mechanism to accomplish the same task. If I pass the include path into the main twig file and use that to access the fileContent everything works as expected.